# VLAN setup on CentOS

Tags: linux, networking

I have two networks I want to separate from each other (no inter-routing). I'm using a Linux host as a router and I have a Juniper switch as the switch (obviously).  My LAN interface on the Linux router is `eth1`, so I created a VLAN called `eth1.2` and gave it an IP in a separate subnet.

```
eth1   => 192.168.1.1/24
eth1.2 => 192.168.2.1/24
```

I have the juniper configured so that there are two VLANs, default and wifi. I did the following commands:

```
set vlans wifi vlan-id 2
set interfaces ge-0/0/12.0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members wifi
set vlans wifi interface ge-0/0/12.0
```

**Question**

I have the WAN interface on the Wireless Router connected to port 12.  The Linux router can't see its static IP.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Update**

I think part of my problem is that I didn't give the router's port on the juniper any VLAN memberships. It should be seen as a trunk according to Juniper's tutorials on youtube.  I think I might have to create another VLAN to act as the "default" since I don't think I can use default anymore. What gives me this idea is that I added the VLAN memberships to the router's port on the juniper and everyone's networking broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this problem, and you will be a bit amused about what I did wrong.

First, I needed to set `ge-0/0/0` (the port that goes to the firewall) on all of the VLANs. This means that I had to create my own default VLAN for the rest of the systems. So I had to do both VLAN1 and VLAN2.  VLAN2 was used solely for WIFI.

Once I fixed that, I had to modify my `iptables` rules. CentOS, by default, has rules inserted  for accepting traffic from `eth1` and `eth0`. But it didn't have any rules for `eth1.2`. So I had to add the IPtables rules that would allow traffic in on that interface (I also had to update the forwarding rules).